# Angular2 add PrimeNG component

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Here are the steps I did to install PrimeNG:

1. `npm install primeng --save npm install primeui --save`
2. Update *Index.html*: (I had to copy directories *primeng* and *primeui* from node_modules to the *assets* folder to get rid of 404 *file not found* error)

   ```
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.6/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/primeui/themes/omega/theme.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css">`
   ```
3. Update *test.component.ts*:

   ```
   import {Calendar} from '../../assets/primeng/primeng';
   ....
   export class TestComponent {
        dateValue:string;
   }
   ```
4. Update *test.component.html*:

   ```
   <p-calendar formControlName="date"></p-calendar>
   ```

> Result: nothing gets shown on page.

**Am I missing something?**

---

**Edit1:**

1. I now think it's important to say I installed the project using **angular-cli**
2. If I add `<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue"></p-calendar>` to test.component.html , I get

   > Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

---

**Edit2:**

I just tried it in another project that is not using angular-cli:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/primeui/themes/omega/theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css" />
    ....
    import {Calendar} from 'primeng/primeng';
    ....
    <p-calendar formControlName="date"></p-calendar>
```

**as soon as I add `directives:[Calendar]` I get Error:**

> http://localhost:3000/primeng/primeng 404 (Not Found)
>   Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/primeng/primeng(…)

[image]

Comment: try the import as `import {Calendar} from 'primeng/primeng';` And have you added `Calendar` to the `directives` array of the `@Component{}` declaration?

Comment: Check my Edit2 please.

Comment: What kind of package manager are you using? Because if you are using `SystemJS` for instance, you have to add primeng to the mapping `'primeng': 'node_modules/primeng'` as well as to the packages `'primeng': { defaultExtension: 'js' }`

Comment: Yes, I am using system.js. I will try that right now, i added a picture to the post. Thanks.

Comment: I tried that with the same result. [Here](https://github.com/muscaiu/ngCris/blob/master/systemjs.config.js) is a copy of my `system.config.js`, maybe u can add a complete answer now.

Comment: Your system.config.js does not include the primeng reference. I've added an answer

Comment: I'm starting to think there is a problem with my pc. I did everhing just like u said, with angular2-cli, and without, installed fresh new project, followed every step on the documentation and still i get the 404 not found. Arrrghhh!!

Answer (score 16):

Update your mapping in `SystemJS` to something like this:

```
var map = {
 'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
 '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
 'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
 'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
 'primeng':                    'node_modules/primeng'//<-- add this
};
```

And update your packages in `SystemJS`to something like this:

```
var packages = {
 'app':                        { main: 'boot.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
 'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
 'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
 'primeng':                    { defaultExtension: 'js' } //<-- add this
};
```

For importing you can use this:

```
import {Calendar} from 'primeng/components/calendar/calendar';
```

or if you just don't care that it loads all components you can just use:

```
import {Calendar} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

For further reference I suggest you look at the [setup of PrimeNG](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)

Answer (score 5):

See at the bottom of [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) page

> Dependencies
>   jQuery UI Datepicker and DateTimePicker

so you have to embed these lines in your index.html which you haven't embed i think so try using this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

also don't forget to list down calendar in the list of directives under @component

## Update

- Shift all your css files of primeng from `index.html` to `angular-cli.json` file. like this

  ```
  "styles": [
      "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
      "../node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css"
       ....
    ],
  ```

move all your primeng js files as well in angular-cli.json file.

- as of now all the components of primeng are converted in module so we have to import all the components in the main module file. (app.module.ts file in my case).

Comment: I will try that too, but now it seems like the big problem is reference errors when i add  [directive]. I tried copying the files again from node_modules to assets, changed references, and same error..

Comment: This worked for me. Put references to js files in scripts array, as follows:
      "scripts": [
        "js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
        "js/primeui/primeui-ng-all.js"
      ],

This allows index.html to be totally clean and worked great for producing distribution package.

Comment: @Kwexi do you know how to do this using webpack?

Answer (score 4):

Hey this is the most updated primeng angular cli quickstart project take a look.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-quickstart-cli

Answer (score 1):

Try adding primeui-ng-all.min.js in index.html

```
<!-- JS for PrimeUI -->
<script src="node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.js"></script>
```

See if this helps.

Comment: @cris Refer this github link - https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-quickstart/blob/master/index.html According this index.html you need add above primeui-ng-all.min.js file in addition to answer suggested by PierreDuc. This is somehow not mentioned in primeNG setup page.

Comment: It's never recommended to add package in index.html file instead use it in `angular.json` or `.angular-cli.json` file

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it your imports in the module.ts file otherwise Angular ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

Add import CalendarModule in your app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({  imports: [
CommonModule,
CalendarModule],  declarations: [CarruselComponent],  exports: [    CarruselComponent ]})
```

Answer (score 0):

This the complete documentation of Primeng Setup: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

Here How we adding a calendar : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Answer (score 0):

**Install PrimeNG**

```
npm install primeng --save
```

[image]

**Install Prime Icons**

```
npm install primeicons --save
```

[image]

**Install Font Awesome**

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

[image]

**Install Angular CDK**

```
npm install @angular/cdk --save
```

[image]

If we now go to package.json, we will see the following primeng dependencies
[image]

Open the angular.json and add the following in the styles section

```
"./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
```

[image]

**Adding the PrimeNG Component in Angular Application**
For adding any PrimeNG Component in Angular we will be following below steps-
[image]

**Reference - https://www.codeusingjava.com/angular/primeng/prime1**
  **Reference - https://youtu.be/4Wk4RgYN9ZQ**

Answer (score 0):

You must first use the npm command to install the calendar
Then add it in your modules file in two parts, imports and exports.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CalendarModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
    exports: [CalendarModule,],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```